# show_in_rest false disable Gutenberg

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

When I declare a CPT with

```
'show_in_rest' => false,
```

Gutenberg editor is disabled for that post type. Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. As noted in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for `register_post_type()` (emphasis mine):

> **'show_in_rest'**
>   *(bool)* Whether to include the post type in the REST API. **Set this to true for the post type to be available in the block editor**.

This is because the block editor (Gutenberg) is completely powered by the REST API. If the post type is not accessible via REST then the block editor cannot load or save the post.